# Show variables set manually for Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

After a pipeline is ran in Gitlab CI, is there a way to show the variables that were used for the job? I am mainly interested in the variables that were set manually in the web dashboard, but all environment variables would be good to see also. I realize that I could just print the environment variables in the job, and that should show everything that was set, but I wanted to see if there was something native/by default in Gitlab that would provide this info.

Tried to find something in the dashboard that would display the vars, but did not see this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way to display all the variables in a pipeline run. Its is upto you if you want to echo any specific variables.

Please note that if they are defined in project `Setting->CI/CD Setting-> Variables` section, and if they are marked as "`Masked`" then they wont show up if you echo them.